# Layer definitions for Web app builder layer list widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Built a layer list widget using web-app builder and integrated it with our Spring application.

I'm trying to pass state parameter to layer definitions through the following code:

```
this.operLayerInfos._operLayer.layerObject.layerDefinitions=["STATE IN ('CA')"];
this.operLayerInfos._operLayer.layerObject.supportDynamicLayers = true;
this.operLayerInfos._operLayer.layerObject.disableClientCaching = true;
```

This is not reflecting in the map.

Comment: Im stuck. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked.

```
var ldefs = [];

array.forEach(operLayer.layerObject.layerInfos, function(layerInfo)){
    ldefs.push("STATE IN ('CA')");
}, this);

operLayer.layerObject.setLayerDefinitions(ldefs);
operLayer.layerObject.supportDynamicLayers = true;
operLayer.layerObject.disableClientCaching = true;
```